# How to move windows files to ubuntu without dual booting?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, backup, 15.10, removing

I'm about to install ubuntu again after using windows for a couple of months and I was wondering if there was way to move my files to ubuntu during installation, maybe dual booting, moving them, then removing windows but I'm not sure how that would work. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can keep the NTFS partition with your files, if you have enough free space. Just shrink the NTFS partition, install Ubuntu, then copy your files to an Ubuntu partition.

After that you will be able to safely remove the NTFS partition and expand Ubuntu partition(s).

That is one of the ways not involving external storage.

Comment: It sounds like the simplest way as well.

Comment: This is the way to go. And yes the only one that is easier is using an external storage or temporarily added  internal disk.